# Обязательно ли нужен ключ для использования Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Подключаю скрипт с API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Но в документации пишут, что нужно получать ключ приложения или можно обойтись без него?

Comment: *"в документации пишут"* -- а чего тогда вы хотите от "здесь"?

Comment: Да, нужен ключ, без него не запустишь свою карту) Получить ключ легко и просто) Просто акк регаешь и создаешь там проект, тебе дадут ключ)

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>`

Comment: если найдёте ошибку в реализации *api*, которая позволит использовать *api* без указания ключа, то, эксплуатируя её, можно не указывать ключ.